# Particle collections: how to keep a sphere inside a sphere?

Tags: particles, collections

I am trying to use the particle system with a collection that consists of two spheres that are concentrical but different in size, in other words a small pink sphere inside a transparent larger sphere.

When I switch on the particle system and choose the collection, the spheres are appearing but are no longer concentrical. Large transparent spheres are just sitting next to smaller pink spheres.
How can I lock the two spheres into staying concentrical when using them in the particle system?

Comment: Is there any reason that you don't want to join them into single object(mesh)? It is totally legit to join two different material and object into one

Comment: What are `Particles - Render - Collection` settings? Did you check the `Whole Collection` checkbox? Do the spheres have their transforms applied? Can you provide some screenshots or a blend file?

Comment: @Hikariztw I tried to join the spheres before using them as particles, however, the join results in a deformation of the inner pink sphere. I will add a screenshot: to the left is before the join, to the right after the join. Sorry, I cant seem to find the option where to add a screenshot?

Comment: @VVV Thank you! I did not check the "Whole Collection" checkbox. This solves my problem.